# Serving traditional servlet through DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 questions.

Can a traditional servlet be used instead of a controller and served through DispatcherServlet?

How can i have a traditional servlet co-exist in a Spring-Boot-MVC (jar) application?

Comment: Have you tried using a filter? You could use a filter and then forward the request to a servlet that you instantiate.

Comment: Depends on what you want. You can always configure it next to the `DispatcherServlet` but you could also wrap it in a `ServletWrappingController` or `ServletForwardingController`. Depending on your needs. The fact tha tyou have a Spring `DispatcherServlet` doesn't mean the normal stuff doesn't work anymore.